# Php Session Variable as desired file name

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am having a dilemma.. my php wont grab the session variable[image]

[image]

This is my session start, I would like to pass my variable to this 2nd page, so I can download the posted file name. Please advise

Comment: For starters, post code, not images of code. Also, please read the message above and fix the problems with your post. It's not entirely clear what you're asking, much less why you're having problems.

Comment: is it name.pdf or $name.pdf?

Comment: hello TRiNE. the picture posted has 'name.pdf' I am trying to pass $name so I can save as the desired file name

Comment: then it should be $name right? otherwise, where do you use $name?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the path to `"$root\\loan_inquiry\\user\\$name.pdf"`, like

```
$path = "$root\\loan_inquiry\\user\\$name.pdf";
```

Note that this is *very* dangerous. You're using user input as a file name, which can go horribly awry in many ways (think, horrifically bad hacking). You'd be better using an ID number or a hash, not raw input.